# Best XML Builder that doesn't use annotations

Tags: java, xml

Can you please recommend a fast XML Builder in Java that doesn't use annotations? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if question is about "simple" XML builder, i.e. something where one explicitly adds elements, attributes etc; or about full data binding solution (POJO to/from XML). Two are quite distinct; many answers suggest full data binders (JAXB, XStream, XMLEncoder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB 2. You can [use it without annotations](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide), defining mappings in XML resources.

Comment: If you don't like that format, the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation has its own format, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

Answer (score 2):

Betwixt, from apache is pretty good for simple stuff. http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/

Comment: Is Betwixt still an active project?  The latest release appears to be 0.8 and the release notes (http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/betwixt-0.8/RELEASE-NOTES.txt) are dated Dec 21, 2006.

Answer (score 2):

[Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) is a better and faster framework. Its easier to learn as well.

Answer (score 1):

[XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html). It is a standard Java class, simple, feature-poor way of serializing objects to XML.

Answer (score 0):

How about [StaxMat](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/StaxMateTutorial)e -- very light-weight, faster than object-mapper solutions (XStream or JAXB), still reasonably easy to use for many use cases.

Of course it really depends on whether by fast you mean time to write code (if so, XStream is probably the thing), or time to run it (in which case simple Stax/SAX wrapping writers, like StaxMate or XMLBuilder are the things); XStream is not particular fast, although it's not the slowest thing around.